# Making C++ library without name mangling with MinGW

Tags: c++, c, dll, g++, mingw

I have several C++ classes which I decided to compile into separate library usable by other applications. Therefore I made a simple C-compatible envelope which wraps C++ classes. The function definitions in the header file are put in `extern "C"` block.

When I compile this using MinGW g++, I get shared library with decorated function names. Each function name has suffix `@ars_size`. To get rid of this names I passed `-Wl,--kill-at` argument to g++. Then I finally got undecorated names.

Then I made a simple C++/Qt application which serves as a tester of the new library. Unfortunately when I include the library's header file into my C++ application, I get linking errors:

```
release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0xd6f): undefined reference to `_imp__TdbGetLastErr@12'
release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x1163): undefined reference to `_imp__TdbGetAsyncErr@12'
release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x166f): undefined reference to `_imp__TdbStop@4'
release/mainwindow.o:mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x1698): undefined reference to `_imp__TdbForceTrigger@0'
...
```

To get rid of these errors I have to exclude `-Wl,--kill-at` during compiling of the library. But then the library is not compatible with C applications. I believe the key is to make MinGW g++ to link undecorated functions. Please does anybody know, how to do this?

**EDIT:** Adding more details requested in comments.

- When compiling the library, I include its header (with `extern "C"`) from the
  source code, so the compiler should be aware of `extern "C"`.
- The library is not so simple wrapper. Actually it creates several C++ objects
  which are operated using handles from C applications. Also it catches 
  exceptions from C++ classes etc.

Klasyc

Comment: When you compile the library source file, do you remember to include the header file where you declare the functions? If not, then you need `extern "C"` in the source file as well.

Comment: There's no harm in including the decorated names in a library that also has undecorated names (via `extern "C"`) meant to be linked from C. What you have right now is a library with C-compatible functions that forward to C++ functions (and expect those functions to be name mangled). You have renamed those C++ functions, but the C-compatible functions don't know that.

Comment: You may be able to avoid exporting the C++ symbols with the `dllimport`/`dllexport` rigamarole, if you really don't like the idea of any external code calling your C++ functions.  But you can't simply rename the C++ symbols.